# How to find the number of values in a plist?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, numbers, plist, element

I have a plist that looks like the following.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <!--
    Translations
     -->
    <plist version="1.0">
        <array>


        <dict>
            <key>English</key>  <string>Hello Mrs./Mr./Miss.</string>
            <key>French</key>  <string>Bonjour Madame / Monsieur / Mademoiselle.</string>
            <key>Spoken</key>  <string>Boh(n)-zhoor mah-dahme/ muh-syuhr/ mah-dah-mwa-sell.</string>
        </dict>

        <dict>
            <key>English</key>  <string>Excuse me.</string>
            <key>French</key>  <string>Pardon.</string>
            <key>Spoken</key>  <string>Par-doh(n).</string>
        </dict>

        <dict>
            <key>English</key>  <string>Do you speak English?</string>
            <key>French</key>  <string>Parlez-vous anglais?</string>
            <key>Spoken</key>  <string>Par - lay vooz ah(n)-glay?</string>
        </dict> 
</array>
</plist>
```

I want to know how to find how many elements are in the plist. For example, there is 3 in the code above. Is there an attribute of plist I can call to find this number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the plist into an array:

```
NSArray *plistArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:pathToPlistFile];
```

and count the number of elements:

```
NSUInteger count = [plistArray count];
```